# Get the center of my text input in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to find a issue to my problem.

I want write something in the canvas, and i would like to set is x and y in relation of the middle of the text and not the start.

Imagine, you wanna write 'hello' in the center of the canvas.

actually you do `ctx.fillText("hello",canvas.witdh*0.5,canvas.height*0.5);`

The problem here is that the H is on center, but not the rest.

Ho can i center the text on the middle of the double 'll'?

Sometinh like `ctx.fillText("hello",canvas.witdh*0.5-"hello".width,canvas.height*0.5-"hello".height);`

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bits of your solution in each answer!

@foz correctly says that context.textAlign will automatically center your text horizontally.

@user3190532 and @philipp correctly say that context.measureText will calculate the text width to do manual centering.

My bit is to approximate the font height for somewhat-accurate vertical centering:

```
var approxFontHeight=parseInt(ctx.font);
```

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YjLKD/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font="18px verdana";


    // Testing
    drawCenteredText("Hello",canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);

    function drawCenteredText(text,centerX,centerY){

        // save the unaltered context
        ctx.save();

        // approximate the font height
        var approxFontHeight=parseInt(ctx.font);

        // alter the context to center-align the text
        ctx.textAlign="center";

        // draw the text centered at [centerX,centerY]
        ctx.fillText(text,centerX,centerY+approxFontHeight/4);

        // restore the unaltered context
        ctx.restore();

        // draw some guidelines just for testing
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(centerX,0);
        ctx.lineTo(centerX,canvas.height);
        ctx.moveTo(0,centerY);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,centerY);
        ctx.stroke();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this first:

```
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
```

and your existing code will do the trick I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the canvas text metrics can help you with this. In Principle, you measure the text before you draw it. This way you can calculate the right position.

look [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-metrics/)

Answer (score 1):

As they said, try this :

```
var textWidth = ctx.measureText("hello").width;
ctx.fillText("hello",canvas.witdh*0.5-textWidth*0.5,canvas.height*0.5)
```

and is centered on the 'll'

;)